AWS Lambda function attempted relative import beyond top-level package
Intro
I developed AWS Lambda function using Dockerfile container but I keep encountering error: 
Unable to import module 'main': attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

It does not even start running.
What adjustments do I need to start it running ?
My Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

COPY source/requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

#COPY main.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY source ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/source/

CMD ["source.main.real_estate_scraper"]

main.py file
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from real_estate_prices.spiders.kolej_na_19 import KolejNa19Spider 
from real_estate_prices.spiders.modern_mokotow import ModernMokotowSpider 
from real_estate_prices.spiders.stacja_wola import StacjaWolaSpider 
from real_estate_prices.spiders.zelazna_54 import Zelazna54Spider

def real_estate_scraper(event, contxt):
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl(KolejNa19Spider)
    process.crawl(ModernMokotowSpider)
    process.crawl(StacjaWolaSpider)
    process.crawl(Zelazna54Spider)

    process.start()

Project structure
image
├─── Dockerfile
└─── source
     ├── requirements.txt
     ├── gcp_key.json
     ├── main.py
     ├── scrapy.cfg
     └── real_estate_prices
         ├── __init__.py
          a lot more but now it inot relevant


The issue here is that you haven’t defined an init.py file in the same directory as main.py. Without this file, Python cannot treat the directory as a package, making it unable to resolve module references correctly.
For example, you need to add init.py to you structure:
source/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── real_estate_prices/

The init.py file in source/ tells Python that source is a package, enabling imports like source.main.
and that happens because main.py isn't in the Top level Module. if it was (or you can update your copy command), you would be able to simply call it directly by
CMD ["main.real_estate_scraper"]

but, in your example main.py is included within source directory and you want to call it from outside.

I tried it also with adding init.py in same directory and also did not worked

now I made adjustments and main.py seems to start running but have problems with latter imports, at least I moved a little bit forward

which type of adjustment did you make, please?

moved requirements to main folder
added init.py file
changed copying commands in Dockerfile
